# Mostrar dados do PostgreSQL em pagina web

Tags: python, html5, postgresql

Sou novo no assunto e acabei empacando na parte web.

Gostaria de uma ajuda para exibir/pesquisar informações do banco de dados PostgreSQL e mostrar em uma pagina web.

Como estou aprendendo Python, gostaria de ajuda nessa linguagem, mas JS também seria interessante para mim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um arquivo em Python que faz a conexão e um SELECT.O arquivo Python funciona certinho, via terminal. **Este é um código base que, a partir deste código, eu fiz o meu**

```
     cur.execute("SELECT id, name, address, salary  from COMPANY")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
       print "ID = ", row[0]
       print "NAME = ", row[1]
       print "ADDRESS = ", row[2]
       print "SALARY = ", row[3], "\n"

    print "Operation done successfully";
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT id, name, address, salary  from COMPANY")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   print "ID = ", row[0]
   print "NAME = ", row[1]
   print "ADDRESS = ", row[2]
   print "SALARY = ", row[3], "\n"

print "Operation done successfully";
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, usando PHP consegui mostrar os dados usando js(jquery).

```
<?php
include_once("./php/conect_postgre.php");

  $consulta_bd = "SELECT * FROM uniao  WHERE regua LIKE 'Co%'";

  $result=pg_query($conexao, $consulta_bd);
  if  (($result)){
      while($linha_usuario = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
          echo $linha_usuario['regua'] . "<br>";
      }
  }else{
      echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
  }
```

Armazenei meu select numa variavel($linha_usuario) ou pode chamar ela de row, passei o id "regua" do input para isso. Logo depois criei uma função em jquery para puxar essa variavel, assim:

JQUERY

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.post('paginaquetemoselect.php', function(retorna){
$("conteudo").html(retorna);
});
});
</script>
```

Onde tem a "paginaquetemoselect", você coloca onde está seu banco de dados puxando registro, a function(retorna) é a função que vai receber esse registro e mostrar na div chamada "conteudo", esse nome ai é o ID da minha div onde quero mostrar os registros. O php é so para você ver como fiz o select dos registros. Foca ali no jquery.